# Set language variable using html/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently creating on online version of a magazine. The magazine is made up of a series of html5 pages. On each page, the user is provided the choice to choose language,"En/Fr".

I would like to know how i can set the language to the chosen one for the whole magazine. For example, suppose I am on page1 and 1 choose lang 'Fr', the other pages too should be loading in Fr. And now, on page20 I choose lang 'En', all the pages should load in 'En'.

Is that possible using html/js??

Could you provide me with a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Why not set a cookie?

Comment: Yeah, use the browsers cache, or looking into something like PHP or NodeJS

Answer (score 1):

This solution can't be achieved using pure javascript and html, as the variables will be lost when the page is reloaded.

You may like to investigate a solution using cookies.

For your example.

To set language:

```
 $.cookie("language", "fr");
```

To read language from cookie:

```
 $.cookie("language")
```

To delete language:

```
 $.cookie("language", null);
```

Comment: never user link of http://www.w3schools.com/ instead use this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Development/HTTP_cookies

Comment: i have removed the example link, and made my own. best of luck

Comment: Thanks I will investigate on the cookie use and provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options: using a cookie, using `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`, and including language identifier in URLs (path part or query part). There is insufficient information (no info about server-side technology used etc.) to suggest a particular approach. In any case, if you want the pages to be found via search engines, each language version should have a URL of its own.